# How to avoid duplicate field values using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have five select boxes .all have an first option "--Select--" and i dont i want to have select boxes have the same option selected ,no duplicate options .how to do this using jquery

Comment: The question is not clear, show the appropriate HTML code.

Comment: its about how to avoid duplicate values across the multiple select boxes using jquery

Comment: You use "text boxes" then "select boxes" VERY loosely.  **show some code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give all the selects the same class and different id's.
Then something like this.

```
var selects = $('.days');
$('.days').change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   var count = 0;
   for(var i=0; i<selects.length; i++){
      if($(this).attr('id') != $(selects[i]).attr('id')) {
         var checkVal = $(selects[i]).val();
         if(value == checkVal) {
            alert("Value already selected, please select a different value");
            $("#"+$(this).attr('id')+" option[value='']").attr("selected", "selected");
         }
      }
   }

});
```

I've added a [JSFiddle showing the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/MVbhp/1/).

Comment: the last line? If you mean `$("#"+$(this).attr('id')+" option[value='']").attr("selected", "selected");` Basically it takes the select element that has been changed and the `option` with the given value (blank in this case) is set as selected.

Comment: Suppose if i want to check for duplicate values across the multiple input text boxes, what is the logic

Comment: Do you mean you want to compare the value in an `input` or `textarea` with the values in other `input`s or `textarea`s to see if the value is the same in more than one? Start a JS Fiddle with your html.